# Finding limit using Riemann integral: $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{\left ( i-1 \right )^{2}+n^{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{\left ( i-1 \right )^{2}+n^{2}}$$
What is the idea behind this? I have watched an MIT open courseware video on this kind of problems, and what I have understood so far is that the lower bound for the integral is the first term in this series, and that you, although this is informal, take some piece of the summation part which is present in every term and take it as the differential. But what about the upper bound? Am I completely wrong about this? Also feel free to point me to some good, quality literature on this subject.

Comment: i think your sum does not converge

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the limit converges, indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{\left ( i-1 \right )^{2}+n^{2}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan 1=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$

Comment: How do you get the upper bound for the integral? It does not seem intuitive.

Comment: @Shemafied: $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n-1}{n}=1.$

Comment: @Shemafied The Riemann sum is designed so that the the upper limit of the integral coincides with the _upper_ endpoint (not the lower one as Jack suggests) of the right-most interval over which you are taking the sum. Indeed for any $n$, the right-most interval is $[\frac{n-1}{n},1]$, so the relevant upper limits and endpoints are all $1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You took one $n$ out of the sum, therefore you have to lower the bounds of the sum by 1, right? Also if you wanted to increase the boundaries of a sum by 1, would it be correct if you changed $n$ to $n+1$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: the difference between the first term and the second term is $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n}{(n-1)^2+n^2}=0$.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. I'm asking whether what i said is true in the general case.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: in general, if we are integrating a continuous function over a compact interval, the same happens.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a hint only:

Write the sum as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\bigl(\frac{i-1}{n}\bigr)^2+1}\cdot \frac{1}{n}
$$
Do you recognize it better now as a Riemann sum?